# Expression Engine: How Do I include a channel within another channel?

Tags: expressionengine

How would I include contents from one channel into another channel?
For instance, If I have a channel of projects. And then I'd like to add items within that project.

```
Project
- Item 
   - url
   - caption
- Item 
   - url
   - caption
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an new free alternative to Matrix: [Grid Lite](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/grid-lite)

Matrix is maybe over the top for your needs, even if it is one of my favorite EE addon.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three approaches here:

1. Use a [Matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix) field within your Project channel to add multiple items to each project.
2. Make a "Project Items" channel, and in that channel add a relationship field (or [Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa) field) that points to your Projects channel. This would link each item with its parent Project. When displaying your Project on the front-end, you'd use [reverse-related entries](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/reverse_related_entries.html) to display that Project's items.
3. Make each Project a category, and then assign each entry in your Project Items channel to the proper Project category. (The downside here is that categories can only have very limited data associated with them - name, description, and image.) On the front-end you'd use the [Channel Categories tag](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/categories.html) to display your Projects (categories), then then list that Projects items below using the Channel Entries tag and the `category` parameter.

Each of these approaches would work!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already have these two channels set up, so Matrix or Grid Lite, while great solutions, would require a lot of migrating work on your part.

Do you have a custom field that relates the two channels right now? i.e. in the Items channel, is there a custom field that allows you to choose (or write) which project the item belongs to? If that's the case, I can work toward a solution from there.